# How to check drive is it virtual, Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, virtual-drive

How to check drive is it a virtual (created using `subst` command)?

`Get-VirtualDisk` doesn't work(powershell 3.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the first character from each line of `subst` output into an array and check if a particular drive is contained in that array:

```psh
$substed = subst | % { $_.Substring(0,1) + ':' }

if ( $substed -contains 'x:' ) {
  # do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the result of running `subst` to get a listing of existing substitutions like:

```
$substdrives = @{};
(subst) |% { $part = $_ -split '\\: => '; $substdrives[$part[0]] = $part[1] } ;
$substdrives | ft
```

Answer (score 0):

`subst` doesn't create a virtual disk, so `Get-VirtualDisk` won't return those drives.

You may be able to use `Get-PSDrive` and look for drives where the `Description` property matches the `Description` property of another drive. For example, on my system I have `subst`ed Q pointing to a path on my C drive:

```
>get-psdrive |where-object {$_.provider -like  "*filesystem"}|select name,description|ft -auto

Name Description
---- -----------
C    OSDisk
D
E
P
Q    OSDisk
U
```

Comment: Thanks, alroc, but in my case descriptions for C and for Z(target drive) drives are empty for both

Comment: The `Description` field is taken from the drive label. If you set that (and you should), you'll be able to use it.